# RubyMine Rails script debugging, how to make lib classes visible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, rubymine

I am trying to debug a script in my Rails project with RubyMine, but the script doesn't see classes that are defined under my lib dir.

The run/debug configuration is running the script in the context of bundle, but the visibility apparently isn't the same as if I had run "rails r script/foo.rb" from command line.

I have tried configuring the debug session to use Ruby script: rails, and then give `r script/foo.rb` as the script arguments.  RubyMine does not accept this as a valid configuration.

Suggestions?  My goal is to be able to interactively debug my rails context scripts as I already can do with code running in the rails server.

Here's the Console output RubyMine:

```
    /home/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby -e at_exit{sleep(1)};$stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17.beta14/bin/rdebug-ide --dispatcher-port 52376 --port 55139 -- /home/michael/work/myapp/script/foo.rb
    Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.4.17.beta14, ruby-debug-base 0.11.30.pre10) listens on 127.0.0.1:55139
    Uncaught exception: uninitialized constant Foo::XLogger
        /home/michael/work/myapp/script/foo.rb:17:in `go'
        /home/michael/work/myapp/script/foo.rb:46:in `<top (required)>'

    Process finished with exit code 0
```

XLogger is defined in /home/michael/work/myapp/lib/x_logger.rb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe I have discovered my own answer/solution, but I offer it for anyone else having this same challenge.

- In the Run/Debug Configurations
- on the Configuration Tab
- the **Ruby script:** field should be `/path/to/rails/app/script/rails`
- the **Script arguments:** field should be `r /path/to/rails/app/script/foo.rb`